# Force neotree to stay at project root

Tags: emacs

I'm using neotree and projectile. I can open neotree at my project root using neotree-find-project-root, and it's beautiful.

When I open a file in a subfolder, it changes the neotree root to the folder that contains that file. This is less useful to me than if neotree view remained the project root.

Can I force neotree to always display the project root folder, and not automatically descend into subfolders?

(Toggling neotree off and on again using neotree-find-project-root will bring it back to the root, but it's a pain to do this manually. There must be a way to automatically do this?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to configure neotree to do this.  You could consider submitting an issue to the developers of [neotree](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree), as this seems like it would be a common feature request.

As a sort of hacky fix, you could try something like this.

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook
    (lambda ()
        (let ((buffer (current-buffer)))
            (neotree-find (projectile-project-root))
            (set-buffer buffer))))
```

This hook is run every time a new file is opened.  It changes the neotree directory to the projectile project root, then sets the current buffer to the original buffer you were working with.

Comment: There's currently an open pull request about this issue: https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/pull/263